# Regular expression in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have an assignment which is "finding the number of strings that contains at least 3 zeros and at most 2 1s" and my alphabet contains just 0 and 1. 
I tried to write like this:

```
(if $line =~ /0{3,}/)
```

but it gave me just 3 "sequential" zeros.

Than I tried this:

```
(if $line =~ /0+0+0+/)
```

again it gave me the sequential zeros.

What is the logic of checking the all string and find the number of all zeros in that string whether they are sequential or not.

Comment: Regex is perhaps not the ideal tool for counting matches.

Comment: Maybe, but my assignment is about using regex.

Comment: You should look into using [Look-around assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#match a 0 + anything + 0 + anything + 0, and not (!) 1...1...1
if (($line =~ /0.*0.*0/) && !($line =~ /1.*1.*1/) ) {
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: But it looks like you have to start with zero. If I write 10000, will it accept? @FtLie

Comment: @user2094920 A regex is not anchored by default: it can match anywhere in the string. To match the beginning of the string, use `^`, like so: `/^1/`.

Answer (score 1):

If it contains at least three zeros, it contains a zero, followed by zero or more characters, followed by a zero, followed by zero or more characters, followed by a zero.

```
$line =~ /0.*0.*0/s
  -or-
$line =~ /^[^0]*0[^0]*0[^0]*0/  # More efficient for strings that don't match.
  -or-
$line =~ /^(?:[^0]*0){3}/       # Avoid code repetition
```

If it contains at most two ones, it doesn't contains at least three ones.

```
$line !~ /^(?:[^1]*1){3}/
```

So,

```
$line =~ /^(?:[^0]*0){3}/ && $line !~ /^(?:[^1]*1){3}/
```

Answer (score 0):

This positive lookahead based regex should work:

```
/^(?=(?:1*0){3})(?=0*(?:10*){0,2}\z)/
```

Comment: what does exactly "?=" means?

Comment: This will match only consecutive `0` & `1`

Comment: @M42: Thanks for your comment, you were right. I corrected the regex.

Comment: @user2094920: `(?=...)` is called positive lookahead. Read more about it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

I would count substitution, after all they're kinda part of regexp, aren't they?

In scalar context, `s{0}{0}g` will return the number of times the substitution was done, which is the number of 0s in the string. So `s{0}{0}g >= 3 && s{1}{1}g <=2` would be the condition you're looking for.

Here is a little test program to test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

while( <DATA>)
  { chomp;
    my( $nb, $expected)= split /\s*=>\s*/;
    # the for topicalizes $nb so we don't have to write it in the condition
    for ( $nb)
      { my $got= s{0}{0}g >= 3 && s{1}{1}g <=2 ? 'ok' : 'nok';
        is( $got, $expected, "testing $nb ($expected)");
      }
  }

done_testing();

__DATA__
00011  => ok
01010  => ok
1000   => ok
000    => ok
0000   => ok
1100000=> ok
0      => nok
00     => nok
1      => nok
11     => nok
111    => nok
10     => nok
100    => nok
1100   => nok
111000 => nok
010101 => nok
```